Decoupling Linearly Coupled Wave Equations with Potentials
I'm currently working numerically with wave equations and I was wondering if one can always decouple two wave equations, with potentials, which are linearly coupled. The system I'm talking about is the following:
$$ \Box \psi  - V_{11}\psi = V_{12}\phi \\
   \Box \phi  - V_{22}\phi = V_{21}\psi     $$
or more compactly
$$   
\Box\left(\begin{array}{c}
\psi \\
\phi
\end{array}\right) = 
\left(\begin{array}{c}
V_{11} V_{12} \\
V_{21} V_{22}
\end{array}\right) \cdot 
\left(\begin{array}{c}
\psi \\
\phi
\end{array}\right) \equiv V \left(\begin{array}{c}
\psi \\
\phi
\end{array}\right)  $$
with $V_{ij} = V_{ij}(x)$.
If I try to diagonalize the RHS matrix, the eigenvalues and as a result the eigenvectors, are x-dependent, so its diagonalized form is :
$$
D(x)=P(x)\cdot V\cdot P(x)^{-1}
$$
where D is the eigenvalue matrix and P the corresponding eigenvector matrix.
If we try to apply this transformation to the initial equation, we have
$$
P(x)^{-1}\Box\left(\begin{array}{c}
\psi \\
\phi
\end{array}\right)=\underbrace{P(x)^{-1}\cdot V\cdot P(x)}_{D(x)}\cdot P(x)^{-1}\left(\begin{array}{c}
\psi \\
\phi
\end{array}\right)=D(x) P(x)^{-1}\left(\begin{array}{c}
\psi \\
\phi
\end{array}\right)
$$
So, the RHS is just fine. Diagonal to the ''new functions'' $\left(\begin{array}{c}
u \\
v
\end{array}\right)=P(x)^{-1}\left(\begin{array}{c}
\psi \\
\phi
\end{array}\right)$. However, the LHS cannot be expressed directly into the terms of $P(x)^{-1}\left(\begin{array}{c}
\psi \\
\phi
\end{array}\right)$.
Also, if we did something like inserting a $P(x)P(x)^{-1}$ next to the $\Box$, then the operator is gone.
Is there anything that comes in mind to help?

You would probably get a better answer on Mathematics, not that someone here couldn't answer it.

Related : Lagrangian for two coupled second order linear differential equations.

Thanks @Frobenius, buut in that case, the analogue to my 'potential' matrix V (there Ω), has constant coefficients. Whereas in my case the coefficients are dependent on space and that's the problem I think.

Since $V$ is space dependent, you will need to diagonalise $\Delta+V$. This is like solving for the stationary solutions of the Schrödinger equation with internal degrees of freedom (like the Pauli equation). Without any more information on $V$, you cannot go further. The same general methods of resolution apply (perturbation, variational ...). By exploiting symmetries, you can find a common eigenbasis and reduce the problem in a simpler form. In general, you will need numerical methods to solve it accurately.
